# Problem with configuration autodiscover in exchangelib

Tags: python-3.x, exchange-server, exchangelib

```
account = common.getExchangeConnection()


File "/opt/apimanagement/common.py", line 68, in getExchangeConnection
    account_smc = Account(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/exchangelib/account.py", line 118, in __init__
    self.ad_response, self.protocol = discover(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/exchangelib/autodiscover/discovery.py", line 24, in discover
    return Autodiscovery(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/exchangelib/autodiscover/discovery.py", line 121, in discover
    ad_response = self._step_1(hostname=domain)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/exchangelib/autodiscover/discovery.py", line 425, in _step_1
    return self._step_2(hostname=hostname)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/exchangelib/autodiscover/discovery.py", line 441, in _step_2
    return self._step_3(hostname=hostname)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/exchangelib/autodiscover/discovery.py", line 473, in _step_3
    return self._step_4(hostname=hostname)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/exchangelib/autodiscover/discovery.py", line 500, in _step_4
    return self._step_6()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/exchangelib/autodiscover/discovery.py", line 551, in _step_6
    raise AutoDiscoverFailed(
    exchangelib.errors.AutoDiscoverFailed: All steps in the autodiscover 
    protocol failed for email 'TEST1.SUPIT@orange-sonatel.com'. If you 
    think this is an error, consider doing an official test at 
    https://testconnectivity.microsoft.com
```

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read the guide to asking good questions at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Also, you may find some useful tips for better formatting of code at https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code

Comment: Regarding the actual question: did you do a test at https://testconnectivity.microsoft.com, as suggested in the exception message? What was the result of that?